# Loading Side bar content before main content in codeigniter view?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Hi i am fetching news from different server and showing in my website, At present the news content are loaded first then the right-side bar is loaded after every page refresh. I want to make Such that first all my header, footer, Side bar(class="span3 sidebar sidebar-right) loads then my news gets loaded

my view file

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <h2 class="title-divider"><?php echo $page_heading; ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 
        <script> function myfunction(){ </script>
      <!--Blog Roll Content-->
      <div class="span9 blog-roll blog-list"> 
        <?php if(!empty($newsArray)) { foreach($newsArray as $result){ ?>
        <!-- Blog post -->
        <div class="media row-fluid">
          <div class="span1 hidden-phone"> 
            <!-- Date desktop -->
            <div class="date-wrapper"> <span class="date-m"><?php echo $result['monthName']; ?></span> <span class="date-d"><?php echo $result['day']; ?></span> <span class="date-y"><?php echo $result['year']; ?></span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="span11">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="title media-heading"><a href="<?php echo base_url('news/detail/'.$result['ID']); ?>"><?php echo $result['TTL']; ?></a></h4>
              <div class="tag"></div>
              <ul class="inline meta muted">
                <li><i class="icon-user"></i><?php echo $result['SRC']; ?></li>
                <!-- Meta details mobile -->
                <li><span class="visible-phone"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="visible-desktop">Created:</span><?php echo $result['day_letter']; echo ' '; echo $result['day']; ?><sup><?php echo $result['daySup']; ?></sup> <?php echo $result['monthName']; echo ' '; echo $result['year']; ?></span></li>
              </ul>
              <p><?php if(!empty($result['CNTNT']))echo $result['CNTNT'].' ...'; ?></p>
              <ul class="inline links">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('news/detail/'.$result['ID']); ?>" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i> Read more</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
        <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
         <?php if(isset($links)){echo $links;} ?>
        </div>
        <?php  }else { ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                        <h4>No News Found!</h4>
                    </div>  
            <?php } ?> 
     </div>
      <!--Sidebar-->
      <div class="span3 sidebar sidebar-right">
                  <?php 
            $this->load->view('news/news_sidebar');
            ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--.container--> 
</div>
<!--#content-->
```

Comment: keep your main content blank at php script and load that area with ajax after page loaded

Answer (score 0):

You should make a different function to fetch news in your controller and call it by ajax on document ready and append the view to the page as the data is returned from this controller.